# Different HPE RAM for Intel & AMD servers

Tags: memory, hp-proliant, hpe

I have a HPE ProLiant DL325 G10 server and the specs for it state that HPE 838089-B21 RAM applies to it.  The DL360/Intel servers accept HPE 835955-B21 RAM, which is about $45 cheaper.  Spec wise both RAM is exactly the same. The only thing that seems to differ are the part numbers.  Does anyone know why this is? And will 835955-B21 work perfectly in the DL325?

HPE doesn't really answer the question. They just tell me that's what the specs say...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spec is the same, but you must follow what HP tell as their motherboard might not support the memory. Graphicly those RDIMM seem different with the chip, so it could be a BIOS problem to support the RDIMM.

On the other side I often use Kingston RDIMM if the HP'S one cost too high. their web site got a model picker, and it offer RDIMM tagged compatible.

For the DL325 G10 the site give [me](https://www.kingston.com/us/memory/search?model=99059&devicetype=8&mfr=HEW&line=ProLiant);

16GB Module - DDR4 2666MHz
Part Number: KTH-PL426/16G

Answer (score 2):

Please follow the rules set forth by the manufacturer.

You have a new modern high-end server system from a premium manufacturer.
There's a reason the product SKUs are unique and detailed in the product specifications. The specifics don't matter since the manufacturer tells you what parts are compatible with the server.

You have not provided a compelling reason to go against HPE's recommendation. They have a hardware compatibility list and the professional thing to do is to comply with that list.